# check mysql column in table for duplicates in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to check the username column for duplicates and if one is found, "username is taken"should echo. no matter what is input as a username "username is ok" is always echoed... what is causing this and how can i change it?

```
$username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM riders WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); 
$uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($uname_check == 0) {
    echo '<strong style="color:#009900;">' . $username . ' is OK</strong>';
    exit();
} else {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: What does `echo $sql;` display just before you execute that query?

Comment: this: SELECT * FROM riders WHERE username='test' LIMIT 1

Comment: Please show what the output of `var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($uname_check))` is. My guess is that something went wrong with your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found out myself as no answer seemed to help:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql, $connect);
```

instead of:

```
$query = mysql_query($connect, $sql);
```

Comment: Ok so you were connecting with `mysql_*` API and then using rest of the functions as `mysqli_*` that is why this code could not catch this error because see in my code I made the connection part a comment because you didn't share that with us.

Answer (score 4):

Let's debug it the right way. When your code doesn't work you ***debug*** it; not just guess things. And to Debug MySQL issues from PHP you have to look at what values are `returned`by those functions? and not just expect the best case scenario. Computer Science is not guess work, its pretty accurate for most things.

**Step 1:**

```
   // $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
```

**Step 2:**

```
    $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$username);
    $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM riders WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    if ($result=mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
     $uname_check=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }
    else
    {
     printf("Error message: %s\n", mysqli_error($connect));
    }
```

**Step 3:**

```
    echo intval($uname_check);
```

By the time you reach here, you will know exactly what is wrong.

After that you can continue with your `if`

```
if ($uname_check == 0)
{
    echo '<strong style="color:#009900;">' . $username . ' is OK</strong>';
}
else 
{
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';
}
exit();
```

Comment: `SELECT *` is really unnecessary. `SELECT 1` would suffice.

Comment: +1; also, Computer Science is mostly "IT depends" ;)

Comment: it now returns "Error message:" thats it, no number, nothing. how is this fixed?!

Comment: Ok so you were connecting with `mysql_*` API and then using rest of the functions as `mysqli_*` that is why this code could not catch this error because see in my code I made the connection part a comment because you didn't share that with us.

Answer (score 0):

Change the logic:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));

if ($query){ 
    if($uname_check > 0) {
    {
        echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';
        exit();
    } else {
        echo '<strong style="color:#009900;">' . $username . ' is OK</strong>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'An error occured while querying the new username';
}
```

And we will be able to understand if your sql query is good.

Comment: if $query is valid it returns true, else returns false.

Comment: @user2953987 so your query will not be fired. Check sql statement

Answer (score 0):

First, try to `echo $username` before your SQL request to check the value;

Second, try removing `LIMIT 1` as this is useless as you do prevent duplicate creation, so it will be 0 or 1 anyway.

Third, try this one: `$username=preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9\.]#i", null, $_POST['usernamecheck']);`

Comment: Also make sure your name field is named `usernamecheck` of course